# Dialogflow Exact Matches

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need Dialogflow to be a little bit more restrictive but only for one specific intent. I have a situation where I use the Greek God HADES but I must NOT accept or trigger the entent if the person omit the S. (HADE)

Right now HADE or HADES are accepted. Overall that is fine, but in this specific situation, I must not accept a missing letter. It has to be the EXACT spelling.

I created an Entity for HADES and use that in my training phrase, but it did not let me restrict the variation on the word. Maybe I am missing a very basic checkbox somewhere or a quotation mark... Any help will be very very appreciated.

----- EDIT
Answer is below: Intent with ML (Machine Learning) disable are Exact Match only. You still can add an Entity with synonyme if you want.

Comment: You can try to change ML Settings in Agent settings but unfortunately this settings are global - try increasing ML classification threshold - with 1.0 value it should be more strict when matching intent.

Comment: Another option worth checking is "Automatic spell correction".

Comment: Very interesting issue. I tried few things but it didn't work. Please post the answer if you happen to find a way to handle this issue.

Comment: So far the best solution I found was to add the misspelled version in the default intent (fall back) so it wont trigger my main intent. If you want to actual try it, here is the link: http://www.cyranostory.com - Each intent has a series of custom payload that trigger various event in the game. (Change color, play NPC voice, blur the screen, open a new clue, etc...) Anyway, that was the only solution I found that made sense.

Comment: Answer from Aravind work wel!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you avoid using an entity? You do have an option to "Disable ML" at the top right of an individual intent. You can add EXACT spelling of the training phrase you want to match inside one intent, and the spelling you don't want to match inside *another* intent.

[image]

Comment: OMG, yes!!! I did not read the answer correctly but this it. So ML is the machine learning that let you have various options for an answer in the sentence structure. Disabling ML mean you need the exact trigger phrase. (Very useful for a product name for example) NOW, if you DO wish to support some variation, you can defined your training phrase as an Entity. In your entity panel add all the supported synonym or acronym for the entity. THANK YOU so much Aravind!!

Answer (score 0):

Its surprising how easy it is to encounter a thing DF simply can't do with only the WWW intents and contexts.

It is *NOT* a scrap and rework to use the javascript subsystem. 
Go to Fulfillment on the left, enable inline editor.

Make a 'for fun' intent and enable it to call the one file, one page program the system gives you as a head start.

The program is called only when "Enable Webhook for this intent" is set on for each intent.

enable webhook for that intent.

Instead of matching intents and context "just for that one intent you made now"... it will call the one page program

It can change the answer to anything...

to see the fragment of code work go to:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_search

and replace the left side code with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to see matching a string exactly working</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var str = prompt(); 
  var allupper = str.toUpperCase();
  var n = str.search("HADES");
  var tellAndrea = "No match";
  if(n > -1) { tellAndrea = "That is it exactly"; }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = tellAndrea;
}
</script>
```

click run on the left above the program, then the button 'try it'

This sandbox can save your 'for fun' programs, and the ABOVE IS HERE AS A HEAD START FOR YOU Too !

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G8Q5GCT88ERZ

see it tells HADE from HADES for instance
Its a bit of a start to get this far. Generally GC asks questions of all sorts ONCE to enable these things.

Its a matter of getting over the notion the environment is fragile. it isn't. only the few intents with a toggle switched to "on" try the program

If you get this far say so here. I will track your progress, help you some too of course.

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Learning an IDE like this etc is a multi step process. Since previous stuff you answered to DF change what it asks you, there is some experimentation required but maybe not much.

Save your intents too and generally do not clobber your work with trying examples that import entire agents. GENTLE !

Making a safe copy of the thing is easy. hit the little gear in DF, find "Export import" and download yourself a zip file of the thing you made so far, for safety, etc...

Good luck
Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
python -v -m ptt20
```

The -v switch for the usual python DF talking agent setup ptt20.py ( push to talk ) helps figuring out answers quite a lot. the inner life of interating actual utterances shows, as per the below....

"It" answers:
import 'click._termui_impl' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x03E529D0>
INFO:root:Recording audio request.

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "are you".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "how is".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "are you there".

INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "are you there".
INFO:root:Expecting follow-on query from user.
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Finished playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Recording audio request.

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to pay".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to pear".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk  to pear".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk  to pretty tree".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to  pretty tree".

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to  pretty tree restaurant".
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.

INFO:root:Transcript of user request: "talk to pretty tree restaurant".
INFO:root:Expecting follow-on query from user.
INFO:root:Playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Finished playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Expecting follow-on query from user.
INFO:root:Finished playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Recording audio request.
INFO:root:End of audio request detected.
INFO:root:Stopping recording.
INFO:root:Expecting follow-on query from user.
INFO:root:Finished playing assistant response.
INFO:root:Recording audio request.

Its real time, word by word. Helps figure out diversity of intents keywords. Having a thing dangle off the computer running python and an example seems to me more effective then a stand along little box.